# Center aligning floated elements

Tags: css

I'm trying to align the links in http://www.jsfiddle.net/uAXkM/ to the center. The links are floated to the left, and the wrapper is positioned absolute. I've tried all combinations of margin:auto and text-align:center, to no success.

How can I achieve this without changing the markup or the positioning?

Comment: To clarify: do you want to have all the links in a single line?

Comment: yes, I want them in single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have them each in its own line, use `a { display: block; }`. [jsfiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/uAXkM/5/).

If you rather want to have them all in a single line, get rid of `a { float: left; }`. [jsfiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/uAXkM/12/).

Comment: To others like me, this solution works for centering *text* elements.  AFAIK, does not work with float's.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

change #content css to

```
#content {
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;
display:table;
margin:auto;
overflow:auto;
}
```